# How can I add captcha to Django login page and receive that?

Tags: django, captcha

I have an app Django and I want add this [JQuery](http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html) captcha to login page (I don't want to use Google Capture). The Django login form is very confusing to add captcha  for me (I read [this form document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#working-with-forms) but this problem is very complex).

I add [JQuery](http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html)code as shown in below, But I don't know how can I send and receive  the captcha value  :

login.html:

```
 {% block content %}
        <form  class="fadeIn second"  method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><label>Please enter the letters displayed:</label>
        <input type="text" id="defaultReal" name="defaultReal"></p>
    <button   type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Login </button>

[![login page][2]][2]
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

But I dont know  how can i get value captcha  for bellow  process :

```
import numpy as np 
#------------------------------ 
def rpHash(person): 
    hash = 5381 

    value = person.upper() 
    for caracter in value: 
        hash = (( np.left_shift(hash, 5) + hash) + ord(caracter)) 
    hash = np.int32(hash) 
#----------------------------- 

if rpHash(request.form['realPerson']) == request.form['realPersonHash']: 
    # Accepted 
else: 
    # Rejected
```

This is default user authentication in Django.

forms.py:

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Base class for authenticating users. Extend this to get a form that accepts
    username/password logins.
    """
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )
    print(username)

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
        The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.
        """
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set the max length and label for the "username" field.
        self.username_field = UserModel._meta.get_field(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        self.fields['username'].max_length = self.username_field.max_length or 254
        if self.fields['username'].label is None:
            self.fields['username'].label = capfirst(self.username_field.verbose_name)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username is not None and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',
            )

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache

    def get_invalid_login_error(self):
        return forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
            code='invalid_login',
            params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [this simple captcha example](https://codepen.io/AlexisBertin/pen/wGBKgK) and  solve my problem for now.

```js
var a, b, c,
    submitContent,
    captcha,
    locked,
    validSubmit = false,
    timeoutHandle;

  // Generating a simple sum (a + b) to make with a result (c)
function generateCaptcha(){
  a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
  b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
  c = a + b;
  submitContent = '<span>' + a + '</span> + <span>' + b + '</span>' +
    ' = <input class="submit__input" type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" required />';
  $('.submit__generated').html(submitContent);

  init();
}


// Check the value 'c' and the input value.
function checkCaptcha(){
  if(captcha === c){
    // Pop the green valid icon
    $('.submit__generated')
      .removeClass('unvalid')
      .addClass('valid');
    $('.submit').removeClass('overlay');
    $('.submit__overlay').fadeOut('fast');

    $('.submit__error').addClass('hide');
    $('.submit__error--empty').addClass('hide');
    validSubmit = true;
  }
  else {
    if(captcha === ''){
      $('.submit__error').addClass('hide');
      $('.submit__error--empty').removeClass('hide');
    }
    else {
      $('.submit__error').removeClass('hide');
      $('.submit__error--empty').addClass('hide');
    }
    // Pop the red unvalid icon
    $('.submit__generated')
      .removeClass('valid')
      .addClass('unvalid');
    $('.submit').addClass('overlay');
    $('.submit__overlay').fadeIn('fast');
    validSubmit = false;
  }
  return validSubmit;
}

function unlock(){ locked = false; }


// Refresh button click - Reset the captcha
$('.submit__control i.fa-refresh').on('click', function(){
  if (!locked) {
    locked = true;
    setTimeout(unlock, 500);
    generateCaptcha();
    setTimeout(checkCaptcha, 0);
  }
});


// init the action handlers - mostly useful when 'c' is refreshed
function init(){
  $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.submit__generated').hasClass('valid')){
      // var formValues = [];
      captcha = $('.submit__input').val();
      if(captcha !== ''){
        captcha = Number(captcha);
      }

      checkCaptcha();

      if(validSubmit === true){
        validSubmit = false;
        // Temporary direct 'success' simulation
        submitted();
      }
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  });


  // Captcha input result handler
  $('.submit__input').on('propertychange change keyup input paste', function(){
    // Prevent the execution on the first number of the string if it's a 'multiple number string'
    // (i.e: execution on the '1' of '12')
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function(){
      captcha = $('.submit__input').val();
      if(captcha !== ''){
        captcha = Number(captcha);
      }
      checkCaptcha();
    },150);
  });


  // Add the ':active' state CSS when 'enter' is pressed
  $('body')
    .on('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        if($('.submit-form').hasClass('overlay')){
          checkCaptcha();
        } else {
          $('.submit-form').addClass('enter-press');
        }
      }
    })
    .on('keyup', function(e){
      if (e.which === 13) {
        $('.submit-form').removeClass('enter-press');
      }
    });


  // Refresh button click - Reset the captcha
  $('.submit-control i.fa-refresh').on('click', function(){
    if (!locked) {
      locked = true;
      setTimeout(unlock, 500);
      generateCaptcha();
      setTimeout(checkCaptcha, 0);
    }
  });


  // Submit white overlay click
  $('.submit-form-overlay').on('click', function(){
    checkCaptcha();
  });
}

generateCaptcha();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);

body { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }

form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 300px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
}

.submit__generated {
  display: inline-block;
  
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    vertical-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  &.valid:after,
  &.unvalid:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  &.valid {
    &:after {
      content: "\f00c";
      color: #2ecc71;
    }
    .submit__input {
      border: 1px solid #2ecc71;
      color: #2ecc71 !important;
    }
  }
  &.unvalid {
    &:after {
      content: "\f00d";
      color: #e74c3c;
    }
    .submit__input {
      border: 1px solid #e74c3c;
      color: #e74c3c;
    }
  }

  .submit__input {
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #42A0DD;
    color: #42A0DD;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: -2px;
  }
}




i.fa-refresh {
  margin: 4px 0 0px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out, color 0.2s ease-out;
  &:hover {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

span.submit__error,
span.submit__error--empty {
  color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}





.submit {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #42A0DD;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 #2C81BA;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #3498db;
  }
  &:active,
  &.enter-press,
  &.overlay {
    margin: 55px 0 46px 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}


 .submit__overlay {
  height: 50px;
  width: 110px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: -5px;
 }








.low-opa { opacity: 0.4; }
.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}
.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}
.form-fields,
.form-success {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.form-success {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <form>  
  <label class="submit__control">
    <h3>Are you human?</h3>
    <div class="submit__generated">

    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
    <span class="submit__error hide">Incorrect value</span>
    <span class="submit__error--empty hide">Required field cannot be left blank</span>
  </label>

  <input class="submit overlay"
         type="submit"
         value="Submit" />
  <div class="submit__overlay"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: This helped a lot - thanks also for linking to the codepen example. Cheers